# How to set image profile on Docker Hub?

Tags: docker, repository, dockerhub

I need to set my image progile on Docker Hub.

How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

From [GitHub](https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/441)..

> You can set a profile photo by using a Gravatar account.
>
> To link that account with your Docker Hub account so that your photo shows up, click on the dropdown for your username in the top right corner.
>
> Click Username > Click Settings > Scroll down to Account Information > Enter your email for your Gravatar account in the Gravatar Email field > Click Save.

Comment: Yes, I see that this answer is not present in stackoverflow. It's important to open an answer here  formatted better then GitHub.

Comment: What does this mean

Comment: It means we are here on StackOverflow and there is no such discussion on this question. Opening a discussion means creating different / better answers.

Comment: You can explain in the best way your answer with a sample image of this process. Sometimes an image is better than hundreds words.

Comment: Is it possible without a gravatar account ?

Comment: @AananthK:It's not possible